# 5th menu item in MAUI Shell flyout goes to "more menu" only on iOS. How to disable?

Tags: ios, maui

5th menu item in MAUI Shell flyout goes to "more menu" only on iOS. How to disable?

I select 5th menu item, goes to "more". I want directly to go to page.

[image]

Instead it now goes to a more page

[image]

This behavior is only on iOS, Android works normally

This is code for generating the menu

```cs
using Meldcode_Core.Views;

namespace Meldcode_Core
{
    public partial class AppShell : Shell
    {
        public AppShell()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            int flow = FlowChoicePage.flowChoice;

            FlyoutItem flyoutItem = new FlyoutItem();
            flyoutItem.FlyoutDisplayOptions = FlyoutDisplayOptions.AsMultipleItems;

            flyoutItem.Items.Add(new ShellContent() { Title = "Noodsituatie", Content = new WebViewPage(2, flow) });
            flyoutItem.Items.Add(new ShellContent() { Title = "Huiselijk geweld", Content = new WebViewPage(3, flow) });
            flyoutItem.Items.Add(new ShellContent() { Title = "Geweld- of zedendelict", Content = new WebViewPage(4, flow) });
            flyoutItem.Items.Add(new ShellContent() { Title = "Seksueel gedrag kinderen", Content = new WebViewPage(5, flow) });
            flyoutItem.Items.Add(new ShellContent() { Title = "Download het protocol", Content = new WebViewPage(6, flow) });
            flyoutItem.Items.Add(new ShellContent() { Title = "Informatie", Content = new WebViewPage(7, flow) });
            flyoutItem.Items.Add(new ShellContent() { Title = "FAQ", Content = new WebViewPage(8, flow) });
            flyoutItem.Items.Add(new ShellContent() { Title = "Veilig Thuis", Content = new WebViewPage(9, flow) });
            flyoutItem.Items.Add(new ShellContent() { Title = "Onderwijs of Kinderopvang", Content = new FlowChoicePage() });
            flyoutItem.Items.Add(new ShellContent() { Route = "Onderwijs", Title = "", Content = new WebViewPage(1, 2) });
            flyoutItem.Items.Add(new ShellContent() { Route = "Kinderopvang", Title = "", Content = new WebViewPage(1, flow) });

            Items.Add(flyoutItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is designed as this. For this, you can add a [feature request](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose) here for this problem.

Comment: Done! Thanx: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/20579